# In flash with as3.0, I have to call a function on the main stage from a movieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have to call a function that is defined on the main stage of my project, and I have to call it from a MovieClip, what can I do?
I'm using flash cs5.5 and AS3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access the MainTimeline from objects on the stage.  Probably the most reliable is 'root', but there is also 'parent' (but only if you MovieClip is a direct child of the main timeline).

```
// root should always work
Object(root).myFunc();

// parent will only work if your movieclip is a direct child of the main timeline
Object(parent).myFunc();
```

Note that you have to cast these are generic Objects (or MovieClip would work) because they return typed classes that don't have a 'myFunc' function in them.

You'll need this code on your main timeline:

```
function myFunc():void {
  trace("My function got called!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When I read your question it sounds as though you have a function defined in an action frame of your main timeline.

My answer may be out of reach for your current project, and ToddBFisher's answer is perfectly right.  That said - I'm going to answer the question differently.

Instead of defining a function on the main timeline, set up a document class, define your functions there, and access the class's functions in your code.  Keep as much code off your timelines as possible.

Downloadable files for Document Class example: http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2008/06/06/actionscript-30-documentclass-in-plain-english/

Setting up an AS3 class: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html

Comment: Although my answer is the least amount of work, and usually preferred by people that use the timeline more than code, I actually prefer this method you are describing myself. +1UP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your movie clip is a direct child of your main stage, in you movie clip you can do:

```
MovieClip(parent).theFunctionToCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your MovieClip has a class, just add it to your main class using like:

**var m:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
**addChild(m);**

then you can get access into it's public function like typing:

**m."functon name";**