# AS3 - how to call a function in the main timeline from a class in a .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have some functions defined at the main timeline, and I need to call them from a class, how can I do this?

I've tried

```
object(parent).function();
```

and

```
object(root).function();
```

but didn't worked

those functions need to be on the main timeline because they removeChild() of the class

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119794/in-flash-with-as3-0-i-have-to-call-a-function-on-the-main-stage-from-a-moviecli

Answer (score 0):

Is your class trying to call the function on the main timeline created inside that timeline ? If so you can store the timeline object and call it. Also stage object might work. Give more details please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after `MovieClip(root).function()` ?

Note that the object you're trying to access `root` from needs to be on the `DisplayList` for this to work.